# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) while getting data from Pokemon API

Tags: json, api, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape the pokemon API and create a dataset for all pokemon. So I have written a function which looks like this:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

def poke_scrape(x, y):
    '''
    A function that takes in a range of pokemon (based on pokedex ID) and returns 
    a pandas dataframe with information related to the pokemon using the Poke API
    '''
    #GATERING THE DATA FROM API
    url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/'
    ids = range(x, (y+1))

    pkmn = []
    for id_ in ids:
        url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + str(id_)
        pages = requests.get(url).json()
    #     content = json.dumps(pages, indent = 4, sort_keys=True)
        if 'error' not in pages:
            pkmn.append([pages['id'], pages['name'], pages['abilities'], pages['stats'], pages['types']])
    
    #MAKING A DATAFRAME FROM GATHERED API DATA
    cols = ['id', 'name', 'abilities', 'stats', 'types']
    df = pd.DataFrame(pkmn, columns=cols)
```

The code works fine for most pokemon. However, when I am trying to run `poke_scrape(229, 229)` (so trying to load ONLY the 229th pokemon), it gives me the JSONDecodeError. It looks like this: [image]

So far I have tried using json.loads() instead but that has not solved the issue. What is even more perplexing is that specific pokemon has loaded before and the same issue was with another ID - otherwise I could just manually enter the stats for the specific pokemon that is unable to load into my dataframe. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way the PokeAPI works, some links to the JSON data for each pokemon only load when the links end with a `'/'` (such as https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/229/ vs https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/229 - first link will work and the second will return not found). However, others will respond with a response error because of the added `'/'` so fixed the issue with a few `if` statements right after the for loop in the beginning of the function